# EF6 Code First, Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having some troubles getting EntityFramework to do what I want. I have an object and I want to keep track of the current and previous state. So when there is an update the previous state will than be changed to the current state and the current state becomes a new object like this:

```
using (var db = new DBContext())
                {
                    var currentPair = await db.CurrencyPairs.Include(c => c.CurrentRate).Include(c => c.PreviousRate).SingleAsync(p => p.CurrencyPairId == pair.CurrencyPairId);
                    var newRate = new ExchangeRate()
                    {
                        CurrencyPairId = currentPair.CurrencyPairId,
                        HighestBid = t.HighestBid,
                        LowestAsk = t.LowestAsk,
                        Last = t.LastPrice,
                        Volume = t.DailyVolume,
                        UpdateTime = DateTime.UtcNow
                    };

                    if (currentPair.AveragePrice == null || (DateTime.UtcNow - DateTime.Parse(db.Store.Single(s => s.Key == "CurrentStartTime").Value)).TotalHours < 4)
                        currentPair.AveragePrice = (t.DailyHigh + t.DailyLow) / 2;

                    currentPair.PreviousRate = currentPair.CurrentRate;
                    currentPair.CurrentRate = newRate;

                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
```

The problem is that I'm getting an EntityFramework error when saving:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded.

The ExchangeRate object has an identity column so the ID should get filled automatically. This thread is the only one that is setting the CurrentRate/PreviousRate properties, there are other threads that read them.

Anyone has a clue as to what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: ExchangeRate object

```
public class ExchangeRate
{
    [Key]
    public long ExhangeRateId { get; set; }

    public double HighestBid { get; set; }
    public double LowestAsk { get; set; }
    public double Volume { get; set; }
    public double Last { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdateTime { get; set; }
    public long CurrencyPairId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This error often caused by forgot to include identity column in user input or the identity column doesn't excluded for data binding. What kind of user input you have & how `ExchangeRate` table class looks like?

Comment: There is no user input, this code is an event handler for a websocket message. The currentPair object comes from the database so it should have an ID. The PreviousRate is also an already existing DB object and should have an ID and the newRate object is being added with an identity column so that should get a generated ID. Or so is my understanding. I've added the ExchangeRate class in the question

Comment: I think some property from `currentPair` has changed, try using modified entity state before `SaveChangesAsync`: `db.Entry(currentPair).State = EntityState.Modified`. It's related to data concurrency while saving with asynchronous mode.

Comment: Adding to Tetsuya's comment: Do you have Tracking enabled?

Comment: I assume tracking is enabled by default, I haven't changed it. Tetsuya Yamamoto, putting it's state to modified seems to fix the problem. Can you explain why in an answer? I can then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add reference property to CurrencyPair. One foreign key id is not enough.

```
public class ExchangeRate
{
    [Key]
    public long ExhangeRateId { get; set; }

    public double HighestBid { get; set; }
    public double LowestAsk { get; set; }
    public double Volume { get; set; }
    public double Last { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdateTime { get; set; }
    public long CurrencyPairId { get; set; }

    public virtual CurrencyPair CurrencyPair { get; set; }
}
```

Here is some [docs article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: I had this earlier, with the same behavior. I removed it because I came to the conclusion I didn't need it. I don't think it should matter for my problem.